# How to save nav_msgs/GetMap service and pass it into a function?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, what I'm going for is to rather having a callback function I want to make my node a client to that service and then pass it to the another function.

```
        ros::init(argc, argv, "dijkstra");
        ros::NodeHandle n("~");
        ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetMap>("map");
        nav_msgs::GetMap srv;
        client.call(srv);
        nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid = srv.response;
```

Running the above code gives me the error-

```
 error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
   nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid = srv.response;
```

I need to pass the map to a function `void dijkstra(???)`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340303/how-to-save-nav_msgs/getmap-service-and-pass-it-into-a-function?/) by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2019-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
   nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid = srv.response;
```

You didn't specify an actual variable

```
   nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid my_variable = srv.response;
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on 2019-12-19**:
Okay, yes I did that. `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid map = srv.response;` I'm getting this-

```
error: conversion from ‘nav_msgs::GetMap::Response {aka nav_msgs::GetMapResponse_<std::allocator<void> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid {aka nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid_<std::allocator<void> >}’ requested
   nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid my_map = srv.response;
```

Also, my function call is `void dijkstra(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& map)`, is this correct?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-12-19**:
Please read the message specification. http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/srv/GetMap.html

`srv.response.map`